# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Freelancing's [first moderator election](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close and the new moderator is:

[image: JohnHC]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

As you might recall, this is a [special *pro tempore* moderator election](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election), which means JohnHC will need to run for re-election along with the rest of the moderators in the event this site graduates.

Please join me in thanking jmort and Amelia who are stepping down at this time.

Since there weren't enough nominees for this election, we are still looking for another volunteer to round out the team. Please let me know if you are interested.

Comment: @user7489: Sorta. I forgot to remove that diamond when I removed jmort's for reasons that are too boring to relay. (I was waiting to remove his diamond until after [The Workplace's](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5997/2019-community-moderator-election-results) if you _must_ know.)

Answer (score 4):

jmort and Amelia, thanks for all your hard work these past 5+ years. I'm sorry to see you guys go, but I understand :)

Hope to see you guys around, and welcome to JohnHC!